# Access privilege on enum type shows oid - can't drop

Tags: postgresql

I have a PG 9.4 database that has an enum type. When I look at privs on that type I see

```
                                                     List of data types
      Schema       |           Name           | Internal name | Size | Elements |  Owner   | Access privileges | Description
-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------
          myschema | myscchema.gender         | gender        | 4    | f       +| postgres | =U/16524          |
                   |                          |               |      | m        |          |                   |
(1 row)
```

Note the =U/16524

I can't find the role in pg_authid or pg_auth_mmebers or anywhere. So can't revoke it.
And can't easily drop the enum since it's tied to a used production table.
And then when I use this db to test restores, it fails since that role does not exist.

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3286; 0 0 ACL TYPE gender postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  role "16524" does not exist
    Command was: REVOKE ALL ON TYPE myschema.gender FROM PUBLIC;
```

Is this a bug, is there some fix (besides upgrading which we're planning to)?

Searched thru catalog views. Have tried revoking all from public.

Comment: Did you try to restore the dump using `pg_restore --no-owner ...`

Comment: No, but I will. Thanks. Am definitely trying to avoid restoring without grants.

Comment: I tried pg_restore --no-owner ...
Same error, unfortunately.